# What is the advantage of SATA that SAS does not have?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, storage, bus

What is the advantage of SATA that SAS does not have?

There are a lot of storage enterprise(For example HGST) that release the same models with two interface as SAS and SATA. And when I see the spec details the transfer rate of SAS interface is two times of SATA's. However why the majority of HDD use SATA interface instead of SAS? And what the advantage of SATA against SAS?

Expect for help. Thanks!

here is the data sheet of HGST Ultrastar He12 ->[1](http://www.hgst.com/sites/default/files/resources/Ultrastar-He12-datasheet.pdf) (the example is for evidence, not for advertisement. I know a little toward Storage Technology)

Comment: As with IDE/ATA vs SCSI a few decades ago, my first thought is "It's cheaper"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer:low price due to the specificity of the consumer market (not demanding market in comparison to data centers)

People upgrade home computers, notebooks so mainstream hardware has to be accessible; also it's cheap as the consumers are not using them 24/7, and even if they do it, it's idling under the windows or the office.

SAS is more business equipment, 24/7 grade, usually sold by OEMs, including support contracts. Prices wouldn't attract mainstream consumers as SAS hardware is designed to heavy use in data centers (just look at SAS specs: 10 DWPD for 5 years while consumer SATA drive would die in less than 2 months of such intensive use).

Same applies for ECC/Registered memory, NVidia Quadro, Xeons, server/workstation motherboards...

So for regular users it's better to stick with SATA, it's simple and compatible with everything, which can't be said for SAS.

Comment: is it means without consideration of price, SAS is better than SATA in performance?

Comment: yes, if you ignore the price, sas is great and durable and excellent performer.

Answer (score 1):

None other than being cheaper.

SAS protocol has more features than SATA - see ["Comparison with SATA"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI), relevant excerpt below.  SAS is better in every way and SATA has no advantage when compared except for price.

> There is little physical difference between SAS and SATA.[8]
>
> - SAS protocol provides for multiple initiators in a SAS domain, while SATA has no analogous provision.[8]
> - Most SAS drives provide tagged command queuing, while most newer SATA drives provide native command queuing.[8]
> - SATA uses a command set that is based on the parallel ATA command set and then extended beyond that set to include features like native
>     command queuing, hot-plugging, and TRIM. SAS uses the SCSI command
>     set, which includes a wider range of features like error recovery,
>     reservations and block reclamation. Basic ATA has commands only for
>     direct-access storage. However SCSI commands may be tunneled through
>     ATAPI[8] for devices such as CD/DVD drives.
> - SAS hardware allows multipath I/O to devices while SATA (prior to SATA 2.0) does not.[8] Per specification, SATA 2.0 makes use of port
>     multipliers to achieve port expansion, and some port multiplier
>     manufacturers have implemented multipath I/O using port multiplier
>     hardware.
> - SATA is marketed as a general-purpose successor to parallel ATA and has become common in the consumer market, whereas the more-expensive
>     SAS targets critical server applications.
> - SAS error-recovery and error-reporting uses SCSI commands, which have more functionality than the ATA SMART commands used by SATA
>     drives.[8]
> - SAS uses higher signaling voltages (800–1,600 mV for transmit, and 275–1,600 mV for receive[clarification needed]) than SATA (400–600 mV
>     for transmit, and 325–600 mV for receive[clarification needed]). The
>     higher voltage offers (among other features) the ability to use SAS in
>     server backplanes.[8] Because of its higher signaling voltages, SAS
>     can use cables up to 10 m (33 ft) long, whereas SATA has a
>     cable-length limit of 1 m (3.3 ft) or 2 m (6.6 ft) for eSATA.[8]
> - SAS is full duplex, whereas SATA is half duplex. The SAS transport layer can transmit data at the full speed of the link in both
>     directions at once, so a SCSI command executing over the link can
>     transfer data to and from the device simultaneously. However, because
>     SCSI commands that can do that are rare, and an - SAS link must be
>     dedicated to an individual command at a time, this is generally not an
>     advantage.[9]

The system chipset defines the base features an OEM has when designing a system.  There are different chipsets for servers versus workstations.  This affects what you are likely to see on the motherboard.